# qiskit - measure only 1 of the register out of n registers

Tags: qiskit

I have created a 9 qubit register:

```
q = QuantumRegister(9)
c = ClassicalRegister(9)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q, c)
```

I want to measure only 1 of the register(let's suppose i want to measure the 5th register.) How do I implement the code?

```
qc.measure(q[register],c[register])
job = execute(qc,simulator,shots = 1000)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(qc)
print("\nTotal count for 0 and 1 are:",counts)
```

My code seems to measure all 9 registers.

Comment: Hi @Hon Lin! Could you elaborate on "my code seems to measure all 9 registers"? What makes you tell us that? The results of the code snippet? If so, could you provide them?

Comment: Hi @Nelimee, the counts give '000000000' and '000000001' as the output, thus not realizing the default setting from the classical register, I jumped into a very wrong conclusion that all 9 quantum registers have been measured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In qiskit, if there are classical bits that are not getting a value through a measurement gate, they will default to `'0'`. Since you set your circuit up to have 9 classical bits, the `counts` will always be bit strings of length 9, even though you are only measuring 1 qubit.

To only measure one qubit, and have that be the only value in the resulting bit string, you need to only have one classical bit in your circuit.

```
q = QuantumRegister(9)
c = ClassicalRegister(1) # Changed from 9 to 1
qc = QuantumCircuit(q, c)
qc.measure(q[register],c)
job = execute(qc,simulator,shots = 1000)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(qc)
print("\nTotal count for 0 and 1 are:",counts)
```